# Why וְעָֽרְבָה֙ לַֽיהֹוָ֔ה מִנְחַ֥ת יְהוּדָ֖ה וִירֽוּשָׁלָ֑͏ִם ? Why not only Yerushalayim?

Tags: history, tanach, prayer-book, book-of-malachi

In [Malachi 3:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Malachi.3.4?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi)

> וְעָֽרְבָה֙ לַֽיהֹוָ֔ה מִנְחַ֥ת יְהוּדָ֖ה וִירֽוּשָׁלָ֑͏ִם כִּימֵ֣י עוֹלָ֔ם
> וּכְשָׁנִ֖ים קַדְמֹנִיֹּֽת׃

Is this referring to the two kingdoms that were separated (and Benjamin had Jerusalem)?

Doesn't that emphasize the time of dissent between the Jews? Shouldn't the prayer refer to a time when all the Jews were together in Jerusalem?

Comment: (1) How can Jerusalem be referring to the northern kingdom, when of so many Judean kings it is said "[מלך בירושל(י)ם](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%22%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%22&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh)"? i(2) The form "יהודה וירושל(י)ם" [is quite common in the Tanakh](https://www.sefaria.org.il/search?q=%22%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9D%22&tab=text&tpathFilters=Tanakh). It would be a hard sell to say that, in all those other places, Jerusalem is referring to the northern kingdom.

Comment: @TamirEvan so it's just the common vernacular? The way of saying it?

Answer (score 3):

Binyamin and Yehuda were both part of the Southern Kingdom. It was generally referred to as Yehuda because that was the more populous tribe. In addition, it was ruled by the Davidic line which descended from Yehuda.

The status of Jerusalem is debated in the Talmud. One opinion says it was not divided among the tribes. The other says it was split between Yehuda and Binyamin. See TB Megillah 26a.